# Verbs with different tenses and different complements joined by "and"

Tags: verbs, tenses, conjunctions

Is it grammatically incorrect to join two verbs with different tenses?

E.g., "This project hoped to and has potentially succeeded in producing one such possible framework..."

Here "hoped to" refers to the original intent when beginning the project and "has succeeded in" refers to the results of the project now that it is near completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a coordination of verb phrases with unlike tenses is perfectly alright.

*This project hoped to succeed. This project has potentially succeeded.*

In your example, however, the verbs take different complements: *hoped to* takes bare infinitive *succeed*, whereas *has* takes past participle *succeeded*.

I'd say you've got a faulty coordination on your hands. On the other hand, as it still reads acceptably well, we might also take the missing complement to *hope to ____* as omitted and understood through context.

There are two options for fixing the coordination:

*...hoped to succeed...*
or
*...hoped to produce...*

Comment: I was thinking the complement for "hope to" would be understood through context, but I do see what you mean. "hoped to succeed and has succeeded in producing" or "hoped to produce and has succeeded in producing" however sound unnaturally repetitive to me. Would you suggest I keep the sentence as it is, change it to one of the options you recommended or use something else entirely?

Comment: I'd keep it as is.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely grammatical to use different tenses joined by 'and'.  "I can and will get the project done." or "I don't understand Postmodernism. Never did and never will." These sentence condense parallel notions into one, but because they refer to the same ideas the meaning is clear.